# Creating a 'Variable Variables' for multiple columns fetched

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

I have 20+ sets of 30+ variables whose variable names are quite similar and I would like to dynamically set the variable names, but I'm having a bit of trouble applying the methods I know, such as creating a `Variable Variables` or `str_replace` to this particular scenario.

Sample Set:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row => $value) {  
        $Height_MIN_5A = $row['Height_MIN_5A'];
        $Height_MIN_5B = $row['Height_MIN_5B'];
        $Height_MIN_4A = $row['Height_MIN_4A'];
        $Height_MIN_4B = $row['Height_MIN_4B'];
        $Height_MIN_4C = $row['Height_MIN_4C'];
}
```

Comment: Any time you think you need variable variables, you probably should be using an associative array instead.

Comment: You're overwriting the same variables each time through the loop. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: And `$row['columnname']` should be `$value['columnname']`. `$row` is just the row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the columns and set variable variables.

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $colname => $value) {
        $$colname = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)